# availableAudioEffects() error when trying to play audio at different speed in Phonon

Tags: python, pyqt, phonon

I'm trying to investigate how to play sound at different speeds with Phonon in Ubuntu. My first thought was to examine what options are available in the function call:

```
 Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects()
```

However, here is what happens when I import PyQt and Phonon and then make that function call:

```
 ely@zaffpants:~/Desktop$ python2.6
 Python 2.6.6 
 [GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import PyQt4; from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
 >>> print Phonon.BackendCapabilities
 <class 'PyQt4.phonon.BackendCapabilities'>
 >>> print Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects()
 WARNING: Phonon needs QCoreApplication::applicationName to be set to export audio output names through the DBUS interface 
 ASSERT: "QCoreApplication::instance()" in file ../../phonon/factory.cpp, line 378
 Aborted
 ely@zaffpants:~/Desktop$
```

I can't find any good threads on this online. Why is this aborting? Please also note that in my current program, I am already using Phonon to play multiple audio streams simultaneously and even have it linked to a Qt thread that manages a custom video player (not in Phonon) to keep the audio in sync even when a user drags faster through the video. So, Phonon must be installed correctly in order to work to this degree and I've been using some backend capabilities features already. Why the abort when I query what backend effects are there?

Any suggestions? And even if they don't fix this error, are there any suggestions for how to force Phonon to play an audio file faster or slower than normal?

**Added**

I solved the abort problem by doing the following: after importing PyQt and Phonon, I created a dummy QApplication and gave it a name, as follows

```
>>> import sys
>>> app = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
>>> app.setApplicationName('myname')
>>> print Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects()
```

But here is the output of the function, which even after specifying one item from the list, is not readable. Not sure how to put it into readable form...?

```
(<unknown>:1848): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_add_log_function: assertion `func != NULL' failed
[<PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f941539ed70>,   <PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f941539ef30>, <PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription   object at 0x7f941539efa0>, <PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f9408032050>, <PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f94080320c0>, <PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f9408032130>]
>>> print Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects()[0]
<PyQt4.phonon.EffectDescription object at 0x7f941539ed70>
```

**Post Script**
As in the comments below, I figured most of this out regarding the audio speed in Phonon, and that thread is here: < [Documentation on PyQt Phonon backend audio effect 'speed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527507/documentation-on-pyqt-phonon-backend-audio-effect-speed/6538526#6538526) >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a list of `EffectDescription` objects.  You can get the api from the [class reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/phonon-effectdescription.html).  For example,

```
>>>for effect in Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects():
       print effect.name()

ParamEq
WavesReverb
Gargle
Compressor
Distortion
Echo
I3DL2Reverb
Flanger
Chorus
```

On another note,  I think something is borked with your installation.  I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, but I don't think you should be getting those error messages.  I don't think you should have to create a QApplication object to get this info either.  I didn't have to on WinXP.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how I can find documentation about how to actually use these effects in PyQt? When I issue this command: >>> print [(str(elem.name()),str(elem.description())) for elem in Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableAudioEffects()], there is an option just called 'speed' that claims to allow me to set speed/pitch. Can I use this to double the playback rate? If so, where do I look to learn how to do that with this Effect?

Comment: That exceeds my familiarity with Phonon, I'm afraid.  All I can do is point you in the direction of the Phonon overview http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/phonon-module.html .  The basic idea is that you call `Phonon.createPath()` to create a path object and then you can call `insertEffect()` from that object to add the effect.

Comment: Also, I found at this link: < http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-capabilities.html > some documentation that explains that since Linux uses DBUS, you do actually have to set up an application and give it a name as I did above. So this installation is probably fine, it's a difference in OS.

Comment: Ah ok.  Sorry to mislead you, then.

Comment: No problem. Also, just for the sake of completeness, I finally figured out how the audio speed option works with Phonon, at least on my system. The link to that thread is here: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527507/documentation-on-pyqt-phonon-backend-audio-effect-speed/6538526#6538526 >